# magento customer resgitration from admin do not ask for password

Tags: php, magento

i want when admin resgiter customer from admin > add customer .

He has to add field for password or tick send autogenerated password.

i want when admin register user he (customer) gets link on click which he will be redirected to screen where he will be able to set his password .

magento is new for me so unbale to guess ho to plan this task

Answer (score 2):

Hope you are doing well!!!

As of Magento is providing the us facility for sending the auto generated password from admin it self. For doing this when ever you are required to add new customer to your magento store you are required to do is Go to admin pannel of your store.

Then follow the below given steps.

->Customers -> Manage Customers -> Add New Customers -> Add all the required Fields in it and check send auto generated password -> Fill out Address related information -> Click On save.

Make sure when you are doing this at that time you website or magento store is in live environment.

Follow above shown steps and you have almost solve your problem.

Hope this solution will be use full to you !!!

Waiting for your positive comments.